# Pagination with large json results using PHP and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

So I have to parse a large set of data that's been formatted as JSON, which is stored in a database.

```
require_once('db.php');
error_reporting(1);
$getUsers = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM mcmmo_users LIMIT 300');
$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers))
{
    $skills = array();
    $tempRow = $r;
    $getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM mcmmo_skills WHERE user_id = '" . $r['id'] . "' LIMIT 300");
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills))
    {
        unset($r['id']); 
        $skills[] = $r;
    }
    $tempRow['skills'] = $skills;
    $rows[] = $tempRow;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"id":"1","user":"user1","lastlogin":"1402936307","skills":[{"user_id":"1","taming":"4","mining":"534","woodcutting":"84","repair":"26","unarmed":"0","herbalism":"108","excavation":"219","archery":"10","swords":"75","axes":"24","acrobatics":"74","fishing":"403","alchemy":"0"}]}
```

But over 15,000 records of it.

I'd like to create a single page application with it using AngularJS. I have this so far:

```
require_once('db.php');
error_reporting(1);
$getUsers = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM mcmmo_users LIMIT 300');
$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers))
{
    $skills = array();
    $tempRow = $r;
    $getSkills = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM mcmmo_skills WHERE user_id = '" . $r['id'] . "' LIMIT 300");
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSkills))
    {
        unset($r['id']); 
        $skills[] = $r;
    }
    $tempRow['skills'] = $skills;
    $rows[] = $tempRow;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

index.html:

```
    <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="mcmmoCtrl">
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Taming</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="stats in mcmmo">
            <td>{{ stats.user }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats.skills[0].taming }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Unless I LIMIT the data, it takes well over 5 minutes to see anything in the view. I'm hoping if there was a simple way to "page" this so I can click on a "more" button, or page 1, 2 without having to change pages.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with using LIMIT?

Comment: How long does it take the PHP to return the rows? Is the PHP query the source of the delay, or the drawing of the elements on the page?

Comment: It's pretty quick, after a second at-least. Rendering on the page without the LIMIT clause takes 3 minutes, and 2 minutes to see the object in console.log(), using LIMIT takes about 2 seconds with 300 results.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries? (like http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which has pagination already built out for you.

Comment: @SamHuckaby I'm not sure how to build that kind of system though.